# Best way to move trailing dashes (-) in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I have a SSIS package which runs on a schedule and pulls in values from flat files. These flat files very occasionally contain negative values, however the negative symbol trails at the end of the value, e.g. `0.01020654-`. When the SSIS package runs and tries to import these negative value into the table, I get the following error:

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

The data type on the column is decimal(18, 10)

These values may not always be the same length, e.g. there may be a different number of decimal places every time. I guess I just need to move the '-' to the front of the value.

I have seen various solutions to the issue using SQL commands such as convert, should I add an extra Execute SQL Task to run this conversion, or maybe add a derived column? I'm just not sure on the best approach and would be interested to see potential solutions for this. The package runs fine 99% of the time, it's only when these negatives appear I'm getting issues.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a Derived Column Transformation to move the `-` from the end to the start, if it's there, and then a further one convert the value from a `dt_wstr` to a `dt_numeric` (can't recall if that is the correct SSIS data type). You can also do that in a single transformation, but I often find it can be easier splitting such operations into multiple nodes in SSIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a derived colum transformation with the following expression:

```
RIGHT([Column],1) == "-" ? "-" + SUBSTRING([Column],1,LEN([Column]) -1) : [Column]
```

If you need to **check for null values** you can use the following expression:

```
REPLACENULL([Column],"") == "" ? NULL(DT_WSTR,50) : RIGHT([Column],1) == "-" ? "-" + SUBSTRING([Column],1,LEN([Column]) -1) : [Column]
```

To **convert values into decimal(18,10)** you can use the following expression:

```
REPLACENULL([Column],"") == "" ? NULL(DT_DECIMAL,10) : RIGHT([Column],1) == "-" ? (DT_DECIMAL,10)("-" + SUBSTRING([Column],1,LEN([Column]) -1)) : (DT_DECIMAL,10)[Column]
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend an extra SQL task. Instead you can try to handle it within the SQL query itself (therefore you should - if not already done - change the source of the dataflow from the table itself to a query):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(
myVal NVARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('100'),('-100'),('100-'),('100.00'),('-100.00'),('100.00-')

SELECT myVal, CAST(REPLACE(CASE WHEN RIGHT(myVal,1) = '-' THEN '-'+SUBSTRING(myVal,1,LEN(myVal)-1) ELSE myval END, ' ', '') AS DECIMAL(19,4)) AS myValDec
  FROM @t
```

Answer (score -1):

in Derive column use

1. (DT_NUMERIC,18,10)REPLACE(column,"-","")
2. Set Derive column to "Add as New Column"
3. Enter your newcolumnname on the Derive Column Name
   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YesCq.png